# Recuperar Header de um Http Response com angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end

Preciso recuperar o Token que vem no authorization e salvar no localstorage, mas, não estou conseguindo.

[image: Token para recuperação]

O meu método de login dentro do meu serviço é:

```
public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
        return this.http.post<User>(this.url, { username: email, password: password })
            .do(user => {
                this.user = user;
            });
    }
```

Acredito que essa informação eu consigo recuperar do subscriber:

```
public login(): void {
        this.signinService.login(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(
            user => {
                this.notificationService.notify(`Usuário logado com sucesso`);
            },
            (response: HttpErrorResponse) => this.notificationService.notify(response.error.message),
            () => {
                this.router.navigate([atob(this.navigateTo)]);
            });
    }
```

Comment: da uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ler o retorno do header dessa forma:

```
http
  .get<any>('url', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('authorization'));
  });
```